# jq: how to select elements with different structure

Tags: json, select, jq

I'm sure this is very simple, but I do not know how to do it with jq.

I have a JSON like [this one](https://jqplay.org/s/dck56xKk8C)

```
[
  {
    "id": "109",
    "name": "aaa"
  },
  {
    "id": "1098",
    "name": [
      "bbb",
      "ccc"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2000",
    "name": [
      "fff",
      "ddd"
    ]
  }
]
```

And I would like to extract the `.name`. When `name` is an array, I would like to take always the first element.

Do I must create an `if` clause, or is there some more direct mode?

As output I would like to have `"aaa" "bbb" "fff"`, but I have `"aaa" "bbb" "fff" "bbb" "fff"`.

Here is what I have so far:

```jq
if .[].name|type == "array" then .[].name[0]?  else first(.[].name) end
```

Output:

```
"aaa"
"bbb"
"fff"
"bbb"
"fff"
```

Interactive example https://jqplay.org/s/fOBuwdj6WS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract all `name`s, but only the *first name* in case the `name` is an array:

```
jq '.[].name | if type=="array" then first else . end' <file
```

For your sample input, the [output](https://jqplay.org/s/S6jNSL0dN9) is:

```
"aaa"
"bbb"
"fff"
```